# How to disable AJAX request's progress bar in Nuxt + Axios? (Not a page loading progress)

Tags: vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

I know how to disable progress bar in whole requests, but i want to keep them on page loading. Do you have a solution?

Answer (score 6):

```
this.$axios.get('URL', { progress: false });
this.$axios.post('URL', { data: 'data' }, { progress: false });
```

It's not working in some versions of @nuxtjs/axios module.
It's working in 5.3.6 version.

The only one solution at this moment - npm install @nuxtjs/axios@5.3.6